# Deploying docker instances based on user input

Tags: docker, deployment, automation, docker-compose

I have a use case where I would like to automatically deploy some services (say 2-3) whenever a user signs up. The services are available as pre-built docker images that are the same for all users, but the configuration (e.g. as specified in docker-compose.yml) would be specific to each user. Anyone can then make HTTP requests to the services.

Currently I'm deploying the services on AWS manually using docker-compose, they are exposed to the web with nginx.

I've looked around and see some tools that could perhaps be used to solve the problem, like Kubernetes, Ansible, Terraform, Docker-in-docker like Sysbox etc., but I'm not familiar with any of them so I'm not sure which would apply best to my use case.